# Writing a partial derivative as a function of time

Tags: partial-derivative, article-writing

I have two time-dependent variables $x$ and $y$. Now I want to write $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}$ at particular time step ($t$).

What is the correct format to write such expression?

$\dfrac{\partial x(t)}{\partial y(t)}$ or $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}(t)$ is correct or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't totally standardised, but I like this notation:
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} {\Big\rvert}_t
$$

Answer (score 1):

We usually write

$$\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_{t}$$

to express the fact that $t$ is hold constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did a mistake and wrote **time constant** instead of **time step**. So does this answer hold also if $t$ was time step not time constant?

Comment: @user594836 Yes it seems not a different thing, if $x$ and $y$ are funtions of $t $the notation is correct. You could add some more detail to check better that fact.